# Bigdecimal for financial calculations and non-terminating computations

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm sure this would be a simple question to answer but I can't for the life of me decide what has to be done. So here's it: assuming we follow the "best practice" of using `BigDecimal` for financial calculations, how can one handle stuff (computations) which throw an exception?

As as example: suppose, I have to split a "user amount" for investing in bonds between "n" different entities. Now consider the case of user submitting $100 for investing to be split between 3 bonds. The equivalent code would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("100.0");
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("3");
    System.out.println(bd1.divide(bd2));
}
```

But as we all know, this particular code snippet would throw an `ArithmeticException` since the division is non-terminating. How does one handle such scenarios in their code when using infinite precision data types during computations?

TIA,
sasuke

UPDATE: Given that `RoundingMode` would help remedy this issue, the next question is, why is 100.0/3 not 33.33 instead of 33.3? Wouldn't 33.33 be a "more" accurate answer as in you expect 33 cents instead of 30? Is there any way wherein I can tweak this?

Comment: divide method also has overloaded implementations which specify rounding mode see this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

Comment: @sasuke, on your update: I have tested `bd1.divide(bd2, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)` ([as shown below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618812/bigdecimal-for-financial-calculations-and-non-terminating-computations/7618840#7618840)) and the result is 33.33`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to use one of the [`BigDecimal.divide()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) methods which specify a [`RoundingMode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

For example, the following uses the rounding mode [half even](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) or bankers rounding (but half up or one of the other rounding modes may be more appropriate depending on requirements) and will round to 2 decimal places:

```
bd1.divide(bd2, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link; now the question is, why is `100.0/3` not `33.33` instead of `33.3`? Wouldn't `33.33` be a "more" accurate answer? Is there any way wherein I can tweak this?

Comment: @sasuke, for `33.33` set the scale to `2` as in the above example.  It all depends on how many decimal places you want to round to.  If you omit the scale parameter, it will use the scale of `bd1`, which is 1 (100.0 has one decimal place).

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that part. All my queries for the time being have been answered. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`divide` has an overload that takes a rounding mode. You need to choose one. I believe "half even" is the most commonly used one for monetary calculations.

Comment: +1; but this still doesn't explain how is 100/3 = 33.3 more logical than 100/3 = 33.33 given that 33 cents are a closer answer when compared to 30 cents.

Answer (score 1):

```
bd1.divide(bd2, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
```

It's an exemple, depending on the rounding you want.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but the reference you have posted is bad & certainly not from a trustable source.

Comment: Well, it wasn't exactly a "reference", more a code example. But ok, point taken I removed the link